Spotlight SAR image formation
I've created a Synthetic Aperture Radar (SAR) simulator and am testing it to ensure its correct operation. One of the last steps is to process the data into a final image, but I'm having trouble with that.
I've shared four files here so anyone can recreate my image formation process thus far.

grid1.gltf is the model used in the simulation. It is just a sparse array of metal plates.
positions.csv is the radar position at each pulse
view_rdm.py is the Python script used to generate the image (requires numpy and matplotlib)
rdm.bin is the range-Doppler map generated by the simulation

Some notes about the range-Doppler map data.

The waveform has already been range-compressed
Motion compensation has been performed such that the origin is always at range bin 128
The data is still in the slant domain
I've introduced zero additional noise sources

Using the command python view_rdm.py positions.csv rdm.bin 20 (where 20 controls the dynamic range of the image in log scale), I get the following image

As you can see, when comparing this image with the GLTF file, there are noticeable areas where the image does not compress correctly, specifically in the middle row, where there seems to be some aliasing, and in the last row (bottom), where energy is compressed into the zero-doppler bin (bin-1024) when there is no structure there.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

First step with any IFP is to process individual point targets (i.e., one and only one at a time) and look at the intermediate results each step of the way. This way you know what the output of each step should be. If you do that, I am 100% confident you will find the source of your error.

@AnonSubmitter85 When I place a single point target not at the origin, I am able to focus that point correctly if I motion-compensate the point target position to the middle range bin. Otherwise it seems like I need a spatially dependent motion compensation which I have no reference material for.

Not sure what you mean. If you a place a point target at the the mo-comp point, do you get constant phase in the frequency domain (in both dimensions! both range frequency and Doppler)? If you offset the target in range (range being defined using the mo-comp point and the center platform position), do you see the correct phase slope in the range frequency domain on each pulse. Likewise if you offset the point in Doppler?

In my previous comment I wrote something by mistake. For a target at the mocomp point, you should see constant phase in the range frequency / slow-time domain, not the range frequency / Doppler domain.

@AnonSubmitter85 When I place a point target at the mo-comp point, I do get a constant phase across the pulses. However, there is no constant phase across range bins because it is a point target, so it only shows up in a single range bin.
As soon as the point target is moved away from the mo-comp point, there seems to be some parallax effect, where the scattered energy from the point target doesn't stay in one range bin across pulses, which seems to be the cause of the smearing/aliasing.

Look at the phase in the range frequency / pulse domain. The target may occupy only a single range bin, but in the range frequency domain it should occupy nearly all of them (depending on how oversampled you are).

I realized that the motion compensation I had performed to focus the image was incorrect. I should have used Stolt mapping, so I'm looking into that now.

It depends on what you want to do. If you just want a range/Doppler image, then remove the waveform (matched filter or whatever) and mocomp to a point. Use IFFT/FFT to get to the range/Doppler domain and you are done. For a lot of applications that is the sufficient. If you want a large, high-res image, then you need to use PFA, RMA,  backprojection, or some other algorithm that applies some type of spatially variant mocomp to all the pixels at once.

Eventually I will be simulating multi-kilometer scenes at high resolution so I will need one of those. Do you have a suggestion in terms of ease-of-implementation?

Easiest in terms of coding is backprojection, but it's also slooooooow. It's usually done a GPU if done at all. Either that or some fancy complicated recursive implementation. Basic PFA is the fastest and usually accurate enough. If it's not accurate enough, there is a spatially variant correction that can be done at the end to fix that. Even with the correction, PFA is faster than RMA, which requires that the data be mo-comped to a line rather than a point. The correction for PFA takes some effort to code though. I don't know. Nothing is perfect.

Do you have a good reference for the backprojection algorithm? I haven't found anything useful yet.

That would make a good new question? I just searched for questions on the topic and didn't find anything useful.

Perhaps this will help. The simplest point target simulator that doesn't consider platform motion during the transit time of the pulse can be written in a couple lines of code like this:
tau_mcp = column_vector_of_the_delay_for_the_mocomp_point_on_each_pulse
tau_tgt = column_vector_of_the_delay_for_the_target_on_each_pulse
f = column_vector_of_the_frequencies_of_interest
x = exp( 1j * 2*pi * f * (tau_tgt - tau_mcp).' );

The .' is to signify transpose, so that a * b.' is the outer product of the two column vectors a and b. The 2-D FFT of the x is your range/Doppler image.

Is the point of this to understand how much phase unwrapping is required per pixel based on its relative position to the mo-comp point?

No. The point of the above is to illustrate how to generate the phase history for a point target.

@MichaelBlazej the point he's trying to make is that you have to compensate the phase according to the frequency of each range bin and the range from the platform to each pixel you are imaging in the scene. You can't just phase compensate to the center point, the phase of all other points will be off.
